# Access custom environment variable without rebooting (using C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, environment-variables

I'm writing a program using C++ that takes advantage of a custom system-wide environment variable. That variable is set by an msi installer. Later my program reads it using GetEnvironmentVariable() API.

The problem is that it seems like the system needs to be rebooted for my custom environment variable to be visible in my program and I'd hate to reboot the system just for that.

What seems to be odd is that if (without rebooting) I right-click on My Computer and then go into Properties -> Advanced and click on "Environment variables" my custom environment variable is in that list but for some reason GetEnvironmentVariable() still doesn't see it.

So is there any other API that I can use that will work without rebooting the system? (As system properties can clearly see it then.)

Comment: You usually don't need to reboot, but the environment is copied when the process starts, so you definitely need to restart your program for it to see new environment variables.  Note that in some cases, you need to restart the program that started yours (e.g. when starting processes via a persistent command prompt).  How does your program get started?

Comment: @Jesse: the environment variable is set by an extenral program (an installer in this case).

Comment: @AndréCaron: Thanks, Ill delete my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this without rebooting the system you need to [broadcast it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104011). Something along the lines of

```
 SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0,
    (LPARAM) "Environment", SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG,
    5000, &dwReturnValue);
```

Explorer handles this message correctly so programs started after this broadcast will see the changes.

1. Also technically you don't need to reboot , a simple logoff and
   login will suffice
2. Another option is to simply [restart explorer](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2003/03/12/3729.aspx)

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. I thought that GetEnvironmentVariable() is a part of kernel32.dll and has nothing to do with the Windows Explorer?

Comment: @ahmd0: I think when Explorer receives that messages it will reload its environment variables from the registry and all new subprocesses will then have those environment variables.

Comment: When a process starts it inherits the environment variables from its parent. When you double click an exe, the explorer process is launching your exe so if explorer is aware of the environment variable so will your process

Comment: @icktoofay thanks. I'm still not sure where should I broadcast that message from? The installer is an msi process and I don't think I can do it from there. As my own process goes then it's a service application that doesn't have access to a user desktop to broadcast any messages...

Comment: You can wrap the code in the answer into a simple exe and launch the exe at the end of your install. Or you can skip environment variable altogether and write some appropriate to disk that your exe can read on startup

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. I'll try that!

Comment: I personally find config files, local to the program directory, way superior to registry variables. They allow install-agnostic applications, which are just wonderful. Don't need it anymore? Just delete the folder! No stuff that could get left anywhere. Want to install on a thumbdrive? Just do it! :)

Comment: Yes, that's how plist files work in OS X but under Windows things are intended to be done via registry. I don't want to reinvent the wheel here...

Comment: @ahmd0: Actually, you are mistaken. The registry was never planned to hold the whole configuration of applications. It was planned to hold a list of installed applications and settings needed for startup. It got perverted into all kinds of uses (copy protection etc) over the years. That's why it gets so bloated and you have to do cleanup once in a while.

Comment: @arne: well that may be the case. That is also the reason why Windows gets so slow with time... But I'm just conforming with the OS standards.

Comment: @Xeo: putting config files into program directory has some security concerns. usually the programm executable folders should not be writable with normal user privileges. since Win Vista this also requires UAC confirmation. I also like 'portable' tools but here i see a unresolvable conflict.

Answer (score 1):

i recently encountered something like this and broadcasting the message is the correct way as explained in this kb (and by parapura):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104011

however, i would suggest to put _T() around the "Environment" (or maybe an 'L') to make sure you are passing in the correct string (ansi or wide). like this:

```
    SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0,
        (LPARAM) _T("Environment"), SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG,
        5000, &dwReturnValue);
```

i used the above in a commandline app. without the _T() the message sending succeeds but my system never seem to receive update of the environment variable.

btw, the 'setx' command line probably uses the same mechanism to update the environment variables. 
also, i'm using this in an atl dll.